# How to send Message object with Box.com's Collaborate Rest API Call?

Tags: box

I am trying to attach message object to "Create Collaboration" API Call. I am able to successfully invite a user to collaborate and the user receives the email but don't see the message in the invite email. My sample request below:

{"item": { "id": "5497784333", "type": "folder" }, **"message": "This is a test message"**, "accessible_by": { "login": "johnxxx@gmail.com", "type": "user" }, "role": "editor"}

There is no documentation in the create collaboration API, but the BOX Web Application somehow accepts message and displays in the email. Could someone please help to determine if there is a way to send message object in the Rest API Call?

Thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a message to the collaboration email invite is not currently supported through the [Create Collaboration API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#add-a-collaboration).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.